# .net Membership get property Value issue

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Essentially I have a basic register and login system setup that uses the .net membership providers. I have no problem setting the values for defined properties in the asp net profile table. However when I do a 'get' on these they are not returning as expected and I have no Idea why. I update a field for a user which is a bool, I change it from false to true. When set to True my get method is still returning the field as false, but I can see in the data that it is in fact true? I can also see when debugging it is true but the `GetPropertyValue` is retruning false?

Get and Set methods:

```
private ProfileBase profile = null;
private UserProfile uP = null;

public UserProfile GetProfile(string userName)
{
    profile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);
    uP = new UserProfile(
        profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString(),
        profile.GetPropertyValue("LastName").ToString(),
        profile.GetPropertyValue("EmailAddress").ToString(), 
        profile.GetPropertyValue("PersonalPhoneNumber").ToString(),
        profile.GetPropertyValue("SchoolName").ToString(), 
        profile.GetPropertyValue("SchoolPhysicalAddress").ToString(),
        profile.GetPropertyValue("SubjectName").ToString(),
        profile.GetPropertyValue("TextbookTitle").ToString(),
        profile.GetPropertyValue("Designation").ToString(),
        profile.GetPropertyValue("SchoolEmailAddress").ToString(),
        profile.GetPropertyValue("SchoolPhoneNumber").ToString(),
        (bool)profile.GetPropertyValue("IsValidated")
        );

    return uP;
}

public void SetProfile(string userName, UserProfile up)
{
    profile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);
    profile.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.FirstName) ? up.FirstName : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("LastName", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.LastName) ? up.LastName : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("EmailAddress", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.EmailAddress) ? up.EmailAddress : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("PersonalPhoneNumber", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.PersonalPhoneNumber) ? up.PersonalPhoneNumber : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("SchoolName", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.SchoolName) ? up.SchoolName : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("SchoolPhysicalAddress", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.SchoolPhysicalAddress) ? up.SchoolPhysicalAddress : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("SubjectName", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.SubjectName) ? up.SubjectName : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("TextbookTitle", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.TextbookTitle) ? up.TextbookTitle : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("Designation", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.Designation) ? up.Designation : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("SchoolEmailAddress", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.SchoolEmailAddress) ? up.SchoolEmailAddress : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("SchoolPhoneNumber", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up.SchoolPhoneNumber) ? up.SchoolPhoneNumber : "");
    profile.SetPropertyValue("IsValidated", up.IsValidated); 

    profile.Save();
}
```

Data being returned (IsValidated is the field in question):
[image]

Data in profile common (IsValidated is the field in question):
[image]

I have no idea why this is happening, any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: probably this cast is giving you the problem:         (bool)profile.GetPropertyValue("IsValidated")

i would propose you do something like
var a = profile.GetPropertyValue("IsValidated");
var b = (bool)profile.GetPropertyValue("IsValidated");

and see what happens. I don't see anything wrong with the rest, sorry if i was not very usefull here

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tested your examples and they both come back as true? In fact when I add a watch to (bool)profile.GetPropertyValue("IsValidated") it is returned as true? But in the user profile its false?!

Comment: then my guess would be that the class constructor is not working properly. i know it may not be pretty, but try to add:

uP.IsValidated =  (bool)profile.GetPropertyValue("IsValidated"); and see if you get what you want. next, try to check if the constructor is working properly by setting true directly into it. You seem to have everything working properly.

Comment: @Spike Cheers buddy you were right these was an issue with my constructor! Thank for the help!